# How to disable scrolling in a QML ScrollView (or TextArea)

Tags: qt, textarea, qml

I want to use a QML TextArea on a mobile device, where the user cannot scroll by swiping through the contents. Instead I want the widget to grow with the content (which I can do by utilizing contentHeight).

But I am unable to disable the scrolling behavior. TextArea has this scrolling behavior because it inherits from ScrollView.

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure I've completely got the scenario but maybe adding `flickableItem.onContentYChanged: flickableItem.contentY = 0` to your `TextArea` can solve the issue? It forces the inner `Flickable` to always stay at the beginning of the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ScrollView's property `flickableItem` to change or disable scrolling behavior. In your case I'd use:

```
TextArea {
    flickableItem.interactive: false 
}
```

If you want to do something else, check out QML's [`Flickable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html), you should be able to use all its properties like with any other `Flickable`.